# How can I add a backup to an already existing installation of Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

I recently installed Windows 7 on a new HD to use on my pc. I did not emediately installed the backup of my previous Thunderbird installation to the new HD, which I have been using for about a couple of months now.

Now that I want to move the old messages from the previous installation of Thunderbird to the new one I see that all the inbox and sent messages are each stored in a single file.

Is there  a way to move that file to the new installation without losing email I have received or sent while using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the many solutions listed [here](http://tinyurl.com/yjhqbcw)?

Comment: Thank you!!! I did not thought of "migrating" - seems I was searching with wrong terms and was not comming up with anything! I think I will manage to get a solution from these results :)